# meteor run android, got this errorAndroid target: Command failed with ENOENT: avdmanager list target spawn avdmanager ENOENT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, android-studio, cordova, meteor

meteor run android

Your system does not yet seem to fulfill all requirements to build apps for Android.

Please follow the installation instructions in the mobile guide:
http://guide.meteor.com/cordova.html#installing-prerequisites

Status of the individual requirements:
✓ Java JDK
✓ Android SDK
✗ Android target: Command failed with ENOENT: avdmanager list target
spawn avdmanager ENOENT
✓ Gradle

i already searched on google and try to add export ANDROID_HOME=${HOME}/Android/Sdk export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/tools export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_HOME}/platform-tools

does any body know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Android SDK Build-Tools 30.0.3` version download then re-build/re-run